# Does Westminster House of Commons have a schedule of upcoming votes?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

I can see details of upcoming business in the House of Commons at http://calendar.parliament.uk/, but how does this translate to votes/divisions that subsequently take place?

Is there a record of planned votes in the Commons, or do votes occur spontaneously as a result of debate? I had presumed that for a Whip to be effective, there would need to be clearly defined details of upcoming scheduled votes. If votes are scheduled and predictable, is there a definitive http://www.parliament.uk source for this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting ("divisions") on the various parts of Bills depends on whether there is consensus within the relevant House, and can take place at any time when Parliament is in session. The Leader of the House (Commons or Lords) plan the timetable to consider legalisation, normally a no more than a week in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The web site has the schedule for particular pieces of legislation or discussion based on what the status of the debate has reached. For example.

[Progress of Public Bills this session](http://www.parliament.uk/business/bills-and-legislation/current-bills/public-bill-list/)

> [Progress of Public Bills List](http://www.parliament.uk/documents/commons-information-office/Public-Bill-list/Public-Bill-List-150416.pdf): 15 April 2016 (PDF PDF 397 KB)
>
> This list was last updated on Friday 15 April 2016 by the House of
>   Commons Enquiry Service, Tel 020 7219 4272.

[Enterprise Bill returns to the Lords](http://www.parliament.uk/business/news/2015/october/lords-enterprise-bill/)

> 19 April 2016
>
> The Enterprise Bill will return to the House of Lords on Tuesday 19
>   April for consideration of Commons amendments in 'ping pong'.
>
> Lords members will discuss MPs' amendments relating to apprenticeships
>   and Sunday working.